NEWB:ConstraintLayout causes Fragment undrawn controls
[]
[]

Hello!
I added two buttons ,inside a RelativeLayout, to the activity_main.xml from a lorem epsom example found in Android Studio.
I added a TextView and EditText next to a Button, to the FirstFragment.xml, inside a LayoutConstraint. but as the FirstFragment.xml picture shows, the EditText and TextView only appear in the (blue/green)'layout designer' but NOT THE EMULATOR.
Why?
I know Android Fragments are subservient to Activities. Is there a default name or other specification for the default fragment?
Thanks
I was expecting the textfield and its label to show up but what I can see is that the rectangle around the button(AppBarLayout) can be moved (blue/green layout block).
